# Custom hostname verifier for Websphere

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, websphere

Hi fellow stackoverflow dwellers,

Oracle Weblogic server provides a convenient method to skip the hostname verification : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/security/ConfigureACustomHostNameVerifier.html in case the certificate is known to be trusted and for some reason, the default certificate verification is not useful. 
I have a similar situation in fact, would like to make the same application work on Websphere and looking for a similar configuration on Websphere application server. Please note that updating the application and using hostname bypassing technique in code is not a feasible solution for me. I need something at appserver level which I can use to keep the application same for both weblogic and websphere based deployment.

Comment: Are you aware that if you omit the hostname check you in effect disable any kind of useful certificate validation? All an attacker needs for a man-in-the-middle attack is then any certificate by a trusted CA, i.e. a certificate for attacker.biz is considered valid. The question is then, why do you use https at all in this case?

Comment: My usecase is this: I have a domain wide certificate of the type: *.host.com . Websphere fails to validate this certificate which is incoming from a different host. I am looking to bypass check for this specific certificate. At the same time, still keep the certificate check for all other connections.

Comment: So in effect you make access to this site insecure. Why do you use SSL at all for this site then? And why does the site returns a wrong certificate in the first place?

Comment: The 'other' site is a trusted (internal) site, which is serving some content to both Internet and intranet sites. It does return the correct certificate.

Comment: So this site provides a certificate for the external name, but you need to access it by the internal name?

Comment: @steffen What do you refer by saying 'name' in external name and internal name?

Comment: There is the name in the certificate, the hostname from outside (external name) and the hostname from inside (internal name). If I understand you correctly the external name matches the certificate name, but you need to access the server by the internal name, right?